# How can I move 1 product at a time in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, jcarousel

I'm using the following code for my bootstrap product carousel.

Can anybody tell me how I can move 1 product at a time?

```
http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/thumbnail-carousel
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the 3 thumbnail span 3s out of each item to start with. Then you will need to experiment with what span you want the single thumbnail to be and the carousel wrapper around it.

here is a bootply for you... http://bootply.com/73830 i've put the thumbnails in a span12 and reduced the carousel width to fit (but that depends on your wrapper)